# how to render rails static 404, 500 error pages without site layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3. In production rails nicely handles exceptions and loads my static 404.html, 500.html etc files from my public directory. However, it loads these files into my layouts/application.html.erb file. I am looking for a way to instruct rails to load these files WITHOUT using my application layout - e.g. just serve the static html file and nothing else. What is the best way to accomplish this?

thanks!

Comment: as i know, rails by default loads these error pages without loading layouts/application.html.erb, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: i'm hosting on heroku and it is loading these files within my app layout...

Answer (score 61):

`render :file => 'public/404.html', :status => :not_found, :layout => false`

Comment: it has to be `:status => :not_found` and NOT `:status => 'not_found'`  That was messing me up, but it's working now.  Thanks!

Comment: @thedanotto somewhere in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

For an **advanced** approach working within the Rails framework. Update your `routes` file:

```
get "/404", to: "errors#error_404"
get "/500", to: "errors#error_500"
```

Add an `ErrorsController` with:

```
layout false

def error_404
  render status: 404
end

def error_500
  render status: 500
end
```

Then within the `app/views/errors/` add your `error_404.erb` and `error_500.erb` files along with a [snazy image](https://www.google.com/search?q=best%20404%20images&tbm=isch) and a search bar.

[More info here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#creating-responses).